# How to find the file used by each service listed on msconfig?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, msconfig

I need to know the file name of each service listed on msconfig. Is that in the Windows Registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see them from Windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services
```

You can see which services start on boot by the "Start"-value and see its file path with its parameters with the "ImagePath".

Answer (score 3):

Hit `Win+R` and type `services.msc`. Then right-click on a service and click on `Properties`, you'll see `Path to executable`. This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the services listed in `msconfig` are also listed in `services.msc`. There, when you click on its properties you should see the `Executable Path`.

For the apps that aren't listed there, I found some of them in the registry, under LOCAL MACHINE (or Current User)\Sw\Win\CurrVers\Run(or RunOnce)

Answer (score 0):

I also believe the MS free app, Windows Processor shows the same information if you were looking for that information under the task manager.  The other answers are better but if you need this data more often, the app is quite a time saver.